# syntaxerror : unexpected token < in json at position 0

Tags: php, json, xml, syntax, opencart

I have a problem in the opencart cart page , whenever the user want to remove an item from the cart the below massage is displayed

```
syntaxerror : unexpected token < in json at position 0
ok 
<pre>remove</pre>{"total":"0 item(s)-0.000 BD"}
```

i believe that

```
remove
```

should not be here , but unfortunately i couldn't find it in the files , any idea ?

Comment: It's written in any core files of opencart. Simply search this word in system folder..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution to this problem

in system/library/cart.php

under : `public function remove($cart_id)`
delete the follwing :

```
   echo "<pre>";
            print_r("Remove");
            echo "</pre>"; )
```

that shall fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your output should be json format, however you're printing those 
`<pre>remove</pre>` as well, which makes your json invalid.

Maybe You could try to use some `grep` in order to locate the file where those strings are coming from.

Comment: please elaborate how to use the grep method to find this ?

Comment: In your webserver, try `grep -lr "<pre>remove</pre>" *`

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about opencart... but your problem is that <pre>remove/pre> is "outside" of the json object, it must to be some thing like:

```
{"total":"0 item(s)-0.000 BD", "the_pre":"<pre>remove</pre>"}
```

What I think is that you have a php code that is making an echo when you make this request (ajax request?) before arrive to the json object output.

Comment: i am trying to find this php code but unfortunately no luck until this moment

Comment: you can try with grep as @RodElias says or with the notepad++ (if the app is in a local folder... or you can download if there is no more way) you can use the "search in files" and browser to the app folder (or folder where you think you might be more likely that the code is) and wait for the result

Comment: There is a possibility that "remove" be a variable, so your code could be like: <pre><?=$var_name?></pre> or like echo "<pre>".$var_name."</pre>" or even echo "<pre>$var_name</pre>".